# When does the complete bipartite graph K n,m have an Euler Trail(Path)?

Tags: proof-verification, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, eulerian-path

So I know that an Euler trail must have no more than two odd degree vertices.

So does this mean that either $n$ or $m$ must be odd? Or is it $n = m + 1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that it has an Euler trail if and only if the number of odd-degree vertices is at most $2$.

In $K_{m,n}$ there are $m$ vertices of degree $n$ and $n$ vertices of degree $n$.

If $m,n$ are both even then all degrees are even so there is an Euler trail.

If exactly one of them, say $m$, is odd then there are $n$ vertices of odd degree. So when can there be an Euler trail in this case?

If $m,n$ are both odd then there are $m+n$ odd degree vertices. When does this give an Euler trail?

Comment: So does this mean that there are two possiblities for the odd occurence? Ie...

n = m =1? and
n =2 and m = odd number >= 1?

Comment: @johntc121 yes, that's exactly right (of course you can also swap $m$ and $n$ in the second case).

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much